# rename a file on unix server using java through Jsch connection

Tags: java, unix

I want to rename a file on unix server.
I am able to connect to the server using channelSFTPObject.
In my scenarion i am creating zip file renaming it with another extension for dropping it on server after tjis i need to rename the file back to .zip on same path in server.
renameTo() is not working Can anyone please help. getting all value false. Is there any other method to do same using Jsch methods?

```
                        File tmpFileObj = new File(destinationPath);
                        File zipFileObj = new File(zipDestinationPath);

                        boolean varCanread = tmpFileObj.canRead();
                        boolean varFileName = tmpFileObj.renameTo(zipFileObj);
                        System.out.println(varCanread);
                        System.out.println(varFileName);
```

Comment: What means "not working"? Any exceptions? or just the file does not exists

Comment: I am getting all value as false. and i have tool to check on server. even ther i can see its not renamed.

Comment: From your code I can not see why you think this is happening on a remote machine. Looks like this is all local to me...

Comment: just above this code i connected to server and dropped the file there in \home\user with name abc.tmp
destination path= \home\user\abc.tmp
zipDestinationPath = \home\user\abc.zip

Comment: channelSFTPObj.put (localPath, destinationPath);

Do i need to connect again to channel to get the files. Is file locked ??

Answer (score 3):

No need to create Object of file...
The only thing is Use the SFTP Channel connection object to rename it.

```
    channelSFTPObj = (ChannelSftp) channelObj;
    channelSFTPObj.put (localPath, destinationPath); // to drop the file from local to server
    channelSFTPObj.rename(oldFilePath, newFilePath); // renaming on server
```

This will replace the previous file with new Name.

Worked perfectly for me.